# Why aren't my functions and methods syntax highlighted in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, syntax-highlighting

I just started using Visual Studio 2019 for writing C++ code, and I thought the syntax highlighting was lacking. Whatever environment theme I use, it doesn't colour the methods and functions, it just leaves them white.

In this blog post below from 2019, a developer is showing off the new enhanced colouring scheme. This enhanced theme colours the methods and functions, but when I use it the colours don't show up.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/productivity-improvements-for-c-new-default-colorization-template-argument-filtering-in-call-stack-window-and-intellicode-on-by-default/

Does anyone have any idea why my colouring isn't working? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Edit: To clarify the issue, even the standard HelloWorld with no imports (apart from iostream) has issues. The main function name isn't coloured correctly.

Comment: C++ is notoriously hard to parse. If you're doing advanced template shenanigans, then many IDEs will fail to detect that correctly. But without seeing an example of your code that's failing to highlight, that's nothing more than speculation

Comment: Sometime it is missing include files... It would be better for you to simplify the project as much as possible and then report the problem to Microsoft... Also, in medium project, if you rapidly make a lot of change with important impact, Intellisense can easily be overwhelmed even of fast i7/32 GB/SSD computer... If it takes say 10 minutes to compile your code, don't expect Intellisense to known everything in 10 seconds.

Comment: To clarify the issue, even the standard HelloWorld with no imports (apart from iostream) has issues. The main function name isn't coloured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display items: > C++ Functions > Default Item foreground has been selected. Besides, please try to repair VS, and try to [reset settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings). If you installed some related extensions, please try to disable them temporary.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Specifically for c++, Visual Studio 2019 has a broken c++ parser, and everything is assumed to be "plain text" unless it's a keyword, operator, punctuation, or a few other tokens. As a result, functions, methods, classes, and even variables are coloured as plain text. It's only slightly more useful than using notepad to write my code.

Some vssetting files I've tried from VS2015 allow colouring of classes and variables, but nothing works on functions. I have no doubt that people use VS2019 just fine with no font or colouring issues, but I think I'll go use VScode for now.

Answer (score 1):

When mine randomly breaks after switching branches, then going to "Project->Rescan Solution" fixes it.